# Truncate List<string> with Helper Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to reduce the size of the titles returned from a query.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> LoadNews(string article) {

    var newsList = new List<string>();

    using (var db = new DbDataContext())
    {
        var newsItem = db.News.Where(x => x.NewsTitle.Contains(article));

        newsList.AddRange(newsItem.Select(item => item.NewsTitle));
    }
    return newsList;
}
```

It is being used with `jquery UI autocomplete` and the above is the source of the data. I have made a helper method to try and wrap the `return newslist`

```
public string Truncate(string source, int length)
{
    if (source.Length > length)
    {
        source = source.Substring(0, length);
    }
    return source;
}
```

How can I make the return types match?
I was thinking of putting a `foreach` in the `Truncate` but can't get it to work.

Comment: You should post the solution you found as an answer.

Comment: Do you want to limit the number of items in the list or the length of the individual strings in the list?

Answer (score -1):

The method looks like this:

```
public void Truncate(List<string> newsList, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newsList.Count; i++)
    {
        newsList[i] = newsList[i].Substring(0, length);
    }
}
```

There is no reason to return the list because you are editing it within the method.

Comment: Neither of the snippets you've provided will do a thing; neither is mutating the list.

Comment: Obviously it was obvious.  `newsList.AddRange(newsItem.Select(item => item.NewsTitle.Substring(0, 40)));`

Comment: edited. Didn't check the code beforehand.  The idea was sound, the syntax was wrong.